# I am having issues displaying with Android political Affiliation App using RadioButtons

Tags: java, android, radio-button

Here is a screenshot image of my app:

[image]

When I click on my "click me button" and I select one of my six political affiliation, say "liberal" it will display "liberal". What I want it to do is when I select "liberal" I don't want it to display the word "liberal" I want it to instead display the definition of liberal , which I called "liberal description" and saved it in my string xml file.

Here is what I wrote in my `MainActivity` section of Android Studio using Java:

```
package myactivity.magadistudio.com.politicalaffiliationapp;

import  android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button showButton;
private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private TextView  showChoiceTextView;
private RadioButton radioChoiceButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 //set up TextView

showChoiceTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.showTextView);

//set up RadioGroup

radioGroup=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupId);

//set up Button

   showButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.showChoiceButton);

showButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



        int selectedOption=radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();


        radioChoiceButton=(RadioButton) findViewById(selectedOption);

        String displayText;


        switch(selectedOption) {

            case R.id.RadioButtonLiberal:

                displayText =getResources().getString(R.string.liberal_description);


                break;
            case R.id.RadioButtonPaleoCon:
                displayText=getResources().getString(R.string.paleoconservative_description);

                break;

 //OTHER CASES

        }

        showChoiceTextView.setText(displayText);

        showChoiceTextView.setText(radioChoiceButton.getText());





    }
});




}
```

Also when I tried to rewrite my code and run it again, I get an error on the line contain the `showChoiceTextView.setText(displayText);` where it says the `displayText` has not been initialized. That is the only error I am getting. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String displayText = null;
```

or

```
String displayText = "";
```

or

```
switch(selectedOption) {

            case R.id.RadioButtonLiberal:

                displayText =getResources().getString(R.string.liberal_description);


                break;
            case R.id.RadioButtonPaleoCon:
                displayText=getResources().getString(R.string.paleoconservative_description);

                break;
            default:
               displayText = "";
 //OTHER CASES

        }
```

if your `switch statement` does not match any `selectedOption`, your `displayText` is not initialized.
Your compiler recognizes that and give you a good hint.

I am pretty sure you forgett the `default` section in your `switch`. It is always a good style to add the `default` section.

Furthermore: remove this line `showChoiceTextView.setText(radioChoiceButton.getText());`

Comment: I ran my program and it generated no errors, but it still didn't display the text I wanted when I clicked on the "Click on me!" Button. When I selected the Liberal option ,for examply , it wasn't supposed to display "Liberal" but instead display the content in the liberal_description string name that was saved in the res/strings/val xml section when I clicked on the "click on me!" button

Comment: you overwrite your edittext value with this line: showChoiceTextView.setText(radioChoiceButton.getText());

Comment: I am not following you. What do you mean overwrite my edittext value?

Comment: Should I get rid of the " showChoiceTextView.setText(radioChoiceButton.getText()); "

Comment: @Jane Poe glad to help you. Feel free to accept my answer with a click on the white hook at the top left of my answer...